# Create an array of all the items in the sub arrays of an array of arrays?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, arrays

Did I say "array" enough for you there? To clarify:

I'm working on organizing and array in an iPhone project.
I have an array of arrays. Each sub array has a list of items.
How can I make a new array of all the items contained in the sub arrays?

I've experimented with the addObjectsFromArray function with little luck.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSMutableArray * allSubItems = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSArray * subArray in mainArray) {
  [allSubItems addObjectsFromArray:subArray];
}
```

If you want to eliminate duplicates, use an `NSMutableSet` instead of an `NSMutableArray`.